# Espressione formale per "è da fare/è necessario farlo"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

Mi potete suggerire qualche alternativa formale ad una frase del tipo:

> L’attività non è urgente ma è necessario farla.

?

Comment: Non trovo che “è necessario farla” sia particolarmente informale, anzi.

Comment: @DaG OK, grazie!

Comment: Si potrebbe dire "L’attività non è urgente ma comunque necessaria".

Comment: @abarisone Sì, una buona alternativa, grazie!

Comment: Concordo con @DaG sulla formalità della frase in questione. Se s’intendesse rendere la frase piú _pesantemente_ e _inutilmente_ formale, ossia «burocratica», bisognerebbe ricorrere a locuzioni desuete e letterarie e a pompose e faticose circonlocuzioni, es. «L’attività non ha carattere d’urgenza; ciò nondimeno, è d’uopo portarla a termine».

Comment: @FerdinandBardamu No, quello mi sembra un po' esagerato :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Certo. Ma è il passo successivo (o meglio, qualche passo ancor piú in là) in un’ipotetica scala di formalità. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una possibile alternativa alla tua frase potrebbe essere:

> L’attività non è urgente ma comunque necessaria